# Python - print some data from response

Tags: python, request, response

I'm making a request:

```
import request in python:
url = "http://myweb.com/call" 
payload  = {} 
headers = {   'Content-Type': 'application/json',   'Token': '123456789' }

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data = payload)
print(response.text.encode('utf8'))
```

and I'm receiving and printing the response as :

```
{"name":"Peter","LastName":JOHN,"RegDate":"2020-03-25T17:34:42.5306823Z","Number":7755}
```

but I want the print statement to show only "Name" and "Number" params. Not the whole response should be printed. How do I do this? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please clarify what exactly the issue is. Why are you doing `response.text.encode('utf8')` ?

Comment: i know only this command to see all what in response. is there other way ?

Comment: What do you mean? Have you read the requests docs? What is `import request in python:` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
import json

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data = payload)
response_txt=json.loads(response.text.encode('utf8'))
print(response_txt['name'])
print(response_txt['Number'])
```

`response.text.encode('utf8')` produces a string, so you need import the json library and convert that string to an object with `json.loads`. Then you can access the keys with `response_txt['name']` and `response_txt['Number']`.

Comment: but response always random

Answer (score 1):

Response is a dictionary object, so you want to print two values from that dictionary using the keys for those values:

```
response_text = response.text.encode('utf8')
print(response_text['name'], response_text['Number'])
```

edit: the dict is actually deeper within the response object than I originally understood.

Comment: TypeError: 'Response' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Comment: TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str

Comment: There's a disconnect then between what you're showing as output for response.text.encode('utf8'), a dictionary, and the errors you report.

Comment: Before he can access the keys in the response he needs to decode the JSON data: `response_text = json.loads(response.text.encode('utf8'))`